# Ajax.Request to external ASP page

Tags: javascript, asp-classic, prototypejs

Hey there. I've been trying and trying to get XMLHTTP (Ajax.Request with Prototype) to request content from an external ASP page. All I get is the error code 0 and null return.

```
function getAuthCode()
{
    new Ajax.Request('http://www.w3schools.com/dom/gethint.asp?q=dada', {
        method: 'get',
        evalJSON: false,
        onSuccess: function(transport)
        {
            alert(transport.status);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) forbids you from using AJAX to access different domains. Here you are trying to use AJAX to access content stored on `http://www.w3schools.com` and unless your script is hosted on this domain it's never gonna work. You can access only scripts that are hosted on the same domain as the page that served this javascript. For example:

```
function getAuthCode()
{
    new Ajax.Request('/myscript.asp?q=dada', {
        method: 'get',
        evalJSON: false,
        onSuccess: function(transport)
        {
            alert(transport.status);
        }
    });
}
```

where `myscript.asp` is a script that you have written and hosted on your own server.

Comment: I realize that, but is there any workaround? It works with other server-side scripts on the server-end, just not ASP. I need to fetch some data from an external webserver which uses ASP. w3schools was an example.

Comment: There are a couple of workarounds: 1. you write a server side script which is hosted on your domain and which will serve as a bridge between your domain and the remote domain. Then you send the AJAX request to your script which will delegate the call to the remote domain. 2. You could use [JSONP](http://niryariv.wordpress.com/2009/05/05/jsonp-quickly/) assuming the remote domain supports it. If it doesn't you are back to option 1.

Comment: Option one would be tedious, it relies on the client's cookies. Unless I could find a way to pass cookies for "example.com" through my server-side PHP script to "example.com" as a proxy, there is no way. I'll look into JSONP.

Comment: @Sam, in your server side script you get the cookies of the client and when you perform the remote HTTP call you can pass them along.

Comment: Getting cookies for my server is no problem, that's a simple GET/POST variable. However, the cookies lie on "the other side" at "example.com". I just thought of a way to get around this, it involves more work for the user though which I didn't want to do. But I don't think there is any other way.